# Latex Table is moved by Appendix Chapter Heading

Tags: tables, double-sided

In the screenshot we see two tables and I want them on the same level..

[image]

I am pretty new to Latex so I really dont know what to do..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, floating environments (figures, tables) are called floating environments because they .. well .. float.  You can however assign the optional argument to be b which could work here (sth like \begin{table}[b] ) I did not test this, which brings me to my next point: You should provide a Minimal Working Example (MWE, google it) so that people can easily recreate your problem and have a easier time helping you finding a solution

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**
So far it seems that @felixwatzlawik is forgotten on his question ... Anyway, I will slightly improve my answer :-)  -- actually I rewrote it. In this I assumed that:

- in appendix (A) you like to have only two tables, without any text
- both tables have to be aligned on bottom of the page
- that content on formatting of table is not a part of question

Considering above mentioned assumptions I suggest to set table instead in `table` float environments directly in the text, for example as `\begin{center} ... <table> ... \end{center}` if table is narrower than text than text width, or directly in it as is shown in example below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{book}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{capt-of}
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

    \begin{document}
    \pagestyle{plain}
\appendix
\chapter{Übersichtstabelle}
\vfill
    \captionof{table}{Übersichtstabelle (1)}
\label{tab:planificacion-1}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{5}{X}}
    \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{2-5}
    &   \multicolumn{4}{c}{some text}   \\
    \midrule
1   &   2   &   3   &   4   &   5       \\
    \rowcolor{blue!20}
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E       \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E       \\
    \rowcolor{blue!20}
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E       \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\clearpage
\mbox{}\vfill
    \captionof{table}{Übersichtstabelle (2)}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{5}{X}}
    \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{2-5}
    &   \multicolumn{4}{c}{some text}   \\
    \midrule
1   &   2   &   3   &   4   &   5       \\
    \rowcolor{blue!20}
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E       \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E       \\
    \rowcolor{blue!20}
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E       \\
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{document}
```

Both tables are forced to bottom of pages with `\vfill`. To introduce of the second page with "Übersichtstabelle (2)" is used `\clearpage` and instead text empty box (`\mbox{}`), which serve as anchor for `vfill`.

For caption outside of `floats` is used macro `\captionof`, which is provided by package `caption` (if is used in your document) or tiny package `capt-of`  (if for caption is used facility of `book` document class). Obtained result is:

[image]